# How do I pass GMT timezones to PHP DateTime object?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

The PHP DateTime object (and more specifically, the DateTimeZone object), [**supports many time zones**](http://il.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). That is all nice and well, but is there a way to pass in a GMT offset as a time zone?

I know it's possible to simply add or subtract hours and apply some math, but I was wondering whether there was a built-in, robust way of doing things (or do I need to make my own abstraction layer for this).

TL;DR How can I pass `GMT+N` values as time zones in PHP's DateTime or DateTimeZone objects?

Comment: is it fine if you can add something like Europe/Paris as timezone ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla: No, the point is the user should choose his GMT time, and not a location time. And I don't want to do some weird mapping.

Comment: Would have had the benefit of DST, but if you don't need that I guess its overkill ;-)

Comment: There is only one GMT timezone (not multiple). You probably mean GMT offsets, these differ per timezone and time. So apart from "that you would like to know", what should be the use of the outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('etc/GMT+2');
```

But there is this warning:

> Please do not use any of the timezones listed here (besides UTC), they only exist for backward compatible reasons.

The list only supports whole hours. Some of your users may live in time zones that aren't aligned by the hour. Also note that if users select a time via a UTC offset, they will have to change it twice a year during Daylight Saving / Summer Time. Selecting by location eliminates that need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My code is not supposed to display the actual time, and DST is also taken into consideration. so I'm good with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the "Etc/GMT??" timezones listed at http://php.net/manual/timezones.others.php

Unfortunately these values are marked as for "backward compatible reasons" only, but you might as well use them if there isn't any other way to do this. Please note that these value do not cover :30 offsets used in some regions like Newfoundland, so you'll run into problems later on.

Another option would be to manually create an array(), mapping each timezone to a timezone name located somewhere in that area:

```
array(
    0 => "UTC",
    1 => "Europe/Paris",
    ...
)
```

Comment: 2 minutes too late, but your answer is valid. Since I'm not actually displaying the actual time (it's complicated), it's cool. I didn't know about the :30 offsets, I'll take those into consideration as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using DateTime and setTimestamp

say the time format is something like this `Sun, 13 May 2012 01:07:00`

```
$currentDate = new DateTime();

$currentDate->setTimestamp(strtotime( $time.' GMT+0400'));
```

> **Note**: You will have to take care of DST

Comment: Looks rather hackish... The point of me using `DateTime()` is to avoid needing `strtotime` or `mkdate` or any of those other nasty functions! Thanks for the suggestion though!